# command to find processor speed on zlinux machine

Tags: command-line, cpu-frequency

I have the following system :

```
$ uname -a
Linux <machine-name-snip> 2.6.18-92.el5 #1 SMP Tue Apr 29 13:16:58 EDT 2008 s390x s390x s390x GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.2 (Tikanga)
```

I need to find the cpu frequency, after a little bit of reading and referring to a links I tried

```
 cat /proc/cpuinfo
 vendor_id       : IBM/S390
 # processors    : 2
 bogomips per cpu: 6396.31
 features        : <some features>
 processor 0: version = FF,  identification = <some id>,  machine = 2827
 processor 1: version = FF,  identification = <some other id>,  machine = 2827
```

now I am not sure how to convert this bogomips per cpu into the cpu speed. I have already referred to [this link](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/BogoMips/#AEN125), but I am not sure how I should convert the bogomips to cpu speed.

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/ -- > does not return cpu frequency for me to use this in order to get a response
```

Edit 1: I have tried all the answers mentioned below in most of cases either the command is not found, or the output does not contain any information regarding the cpu frequency. I am guessing there must be something wrong with the installation of the machine as a lot of the below mentioned commands are not found.

Comment: have you tried `lspcu` command ?

Answer (score 2):

Try `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq` command

Comment: the systems though it has 2 cpu's does not have above directory structure with the cpufreq dir. --------$ ls /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1
                                  ---------result : crash_notes  online  topology

Comment: For me it was `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq`.

Answer (score 2):

`cat /proc/cpuinfo`

output also has the cpu MHz

### sample out

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x14
cpu MHz     : 3101.000
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
...
```

Comment: on the particular zlinux machine that I am using there is no entry for cpu frenquency at all. This command would definitely help me to get the frequency in any other linux machine

Comment: On s390 (mainframe) the /proc/cpuinfo does not contain the frequency

Answer (score 1):

[Bogomips](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/BogoMips) (see specially section 3.1 of the linked document) is a totally bogus measure of processor speed reported by the Linux kernel. Also different architectures (or even implementations of the same architecture) can't be compared just by "clock speed". E.g., it used to be that AMD CPUs at the same clock speed were *much* faster than the respective intel offerings. RISC CPUs used to be faster at the same clock speed than CISC processors.

For any specific workload, the exact mix of integer/floating point/other instructions, many/few branches, cache performance, and the list goes on for a *long* time passing through compiler savvy and device performance, have a relevant say on final performance.

Answer (score 0):

There are various programs/files that give you this information:

1. `lscpu | grep -i MHz`
2. `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i mhz`  (though this information is apparently absent in your system)
3. `cpufreq-info`, this one is the most comprehensive:

   ```
   $ cpufreq-info 
   cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
   Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
   analyzing CPU 0:
     driver: acpi-cpufreq
     CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
     CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
     maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
     hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 2.67 GHz
     available frequency steps: 2.67 GHz, 2.67 GHz, 2.53 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.27 GHz, 2.13 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.87 GHz, 1.73 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.47 GHz, 1.33 GHz, 1.20 GHz
     available cpufreq governors: ondemand, performance
     current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 2.67 GHz.
                     The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                     within this range.
     current CPU frequency is 1.20 GHz.
   analyzing CPU 1:
     driver: acpi-cpufreq
     CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 1
     CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
     maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
     hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 2.67 GHz
     available frequency steps: 2.67 GHz, 2.67 GHz, 2.53 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.27 GHz, 2.13 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.87 GHz, 1.73 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.47 GHz, 1.33 GHz, 1.20 GHz
     available cpufreq governors: ondemand, performance
     current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 2.67 GHz.
                     The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                     within this range.
     current CPU frequency is 1.20 GHz.
   analyzing CPU 2:
     driver: acpi-cpufreq
     CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 2
     CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 2
     maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
     hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 2.67 GHz
     available frequency steps: 2.67 GHz, 2.67 GHz, 2.53 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.27 GHz, 2.13 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.87 GHz, 1.73 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.47 GHz, 1.33 GHz, 1.20 GHz
     available cpufreq governors: ondemand, performance
     current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 2.67 GHz.
                     The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                     within this range.
     current CPU frequency is 1.20 GHz.
   analyzing CPU 3:
     driver: acpi-cpufreq
     CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 3
     CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 3
     maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
     hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 2.67 GHz
     available frequency steps: 2.67 GHz, 2.67 GHz, 2.53 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.27 GHz, 2.13 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.87 GHz, 1.73 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.47 GHz, 1.33 GHz, 1.20 GHz
     available cpufreq governors: ondemand, performance
     current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 2.67 GHz.
                     The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                     within this range.
     current CPU frequency is 1.20 GHz.
   ```